# Any tutorials for installing windows 10 guest on VirtualBox on ubuntu 15.10 host

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I'm trying to install a Windows 10 guest on VirtualBox with a Ubuntu 15.10 host.  I was sold a USB Stick with Windows 10 and then found that VirtualBox can't install from a USB Stick. I downloaded a Windows 10 iso from the Microsoft site.

I start to create the Guest and get to the point VB is asking for the optical virtual device and get

```
 Failed to open the disk image file /home/roye/Downloads/Win10_1511_English_x64.iso.

Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/roye/Downloads/Win10_1511_English_x64.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component: MediumWrap
Interface: IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee: IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Any ideas or pointers to a good tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should look for VirtualBox support?

Comment: Could it be a corrupted download?

Comment: Might be a corrupted download. I'd downloaded it 2 different times days apart a get the same error.  Going to create an ISO by downloading on a Windows PC and see if that ISO works...

Answer (score 0):

From all appearances, the either the ISO file was corrupted during the download from the Windows 10 download site. I tried to install directly from the ~/Download directory and from a DVD I created from the Download directory. Both caused the same error message.

It was strange that I had downloaded the ISO on two different days and both had the same problem.

Fortunately, my wife's computer is still Windows. I used Microsoft's Media Creator (found as a option on the Windows 10 download site) to download and burn the ISO to a DVD. I then used that DVD to create Windows 10 in VirtualBox.

Windows 10 is up and running. Now to test my "favorite Windows only" app.

Comment: you downloaded, or created a sort of snapshot?  Asking in the context of licensing...